# VPN subnet "collision"?

Tags: vpn

Many routers are using the same default local networks, such as 192.168.1.0/24 or - as in my case - 192.168.178.0/24.

Is it correct to assume, that it might be a good idea to change my network settings to something "non-standard" such as 172.17.47.0/24 in order to make things less complicated if I ever want to create a VPN to a person who might otherwise use the same subnet at home?

At the moment, I don't have any plans of creating a VPN, but I'd like to keep my options open without having to change my network configuration again.

Edit: The reason I'm asking is that I'm about to introduce an [eBlocker device](https://www.eblocker.com/) to my network which will likely make future changes more complicated.

Comment: A home network usually is half a dozen devices, you can usually renumber it in 15-30 minutes.  Not sure why you would worry about it now, vs when it when it becomes a problem.  Anyway, just avoid the most common 3 `192.168.0.0/24`, `192.168.1.0/24`, and `10.0.0.0/24`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is a good idea. If you are setting up a new network then spent the minute to change the default settings to something else.

If you already have everything set up, then you might as well do that after a conflict occurs. Time is spent either way, and if you already have things working and no current conflict then why bother?

Still, when setting up a new network 172.16.0.0/12 is a very nice range...

Comment: Why is it a very nice range?

Comment: Because there are three ranges in RFC1918. 192.168.0.0/16. Most SOHO devices users this. Then there is 10.0.0.0/8. I mostly see those at work places which lack their own normal/public IP range.  172.16.0.0/12 is harder since it does not end in 'even subnet boundaries. It tends to be rarely used.  Rarely used means less change of conflict.

Comment: Why do you think 10.0.0.0 is used by orgs who have a lack of public IPs? Surely the reason for businesses to use 10.0.0.0 is address availability for many devices and physical sites, which has no relation to how many WAN IPs they have

Comment: 3 places I worked, which all were large. All used 10.0.0.0. Neither had more than a few real IPs. Granted, a small sample set.

Comment: I don't see the correlation between LAN IPs and number of WAN IPs owned by an org, both serve different purposes so how can you correlate the two?

Comment: If you have sufficient real IPs (e.g. a whole /16) then there is no need to uses things like RFC1918 ranges. You just use the real ones and avoid tons of headaches which come with the curse called NAT.